# R assignment failed

Tags: r, variable-assignment

When I reassign the title,it does'nt work. I don't konw why.Here are my code and my title. however,the terminnal does't tell any wrong thing seems that it work.But actually it is not work. Can anyone tell me how can i solve it?

```
#载入包
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(mice)
library(scales)
library(randomForest)


#载入数据
setwd("C:/Users/Kaifan/Documents/R_study/five")
train <- read.csv("train.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test <- read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- bind_rows(train,test)

train.row <- 1:nrow(train)
test.row <- (1+nrow(train)):(nrow(train)+nrow(test))

#数据查看
str(data)

#特征工程之一(名字)
data$title <- gsub('(.*,)|(\\..*)','',data$Name)
#通过性别展示称呼头衔
table(data$Sex,data$title)

#将性别头衔进行整合
# Sir <- c('Capt','Don','Major','Col','Rev','Jonkheer')
# Lady <- c('Dona','Lady','the Countess',
#           'Mlle','Mme','Ms')
data$title[data$title %in% c('Capt','Don','Major','Col','Rev','Jonkheer')] <- 'Sir'
data$title[data$title  %in% c('Dona','Lady','the Countess',
                              'Mlle','Mme','Ms')] <- 'Lady'

#再次通过性别展示头衔
table(data$Sex,data$title)
```

[image: error when I reassign my title parameter]

Comment: Keep attention to white spaces. Very likely values of `data$title` are different from what might appear. Try `unique(data$title)` (post the result, it might help) and see if there are any white space hanging around (if so, you might use `trimws` to get rid of them).

Comment: OK,thank you for your help.